# What is the biggest hard-shell hand luggage model (by usable volume) that fits Ryanair's official limits and is sold in Europe?

Tags: hand-luggage, shopping, ryanair

I often travel with Ryanair/Wizz Air and have a piece of luggage that fits their limits. However it's awkwardly constructed and a lot of the usable space is filled by the wheels and the handles.

What hard-shell model (currently available on the market) has the largest volume usable for storage and is still accepted on Ryanair's flights as hand luggage?

To [quote](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage#0-1) Ryanair:

> You can carry one cabin bag weighing up to 10 kg with maximum dimensions of **55cm x 40cm x 20cm**.

The hand luggage should be available for sale in Europe. I assume a carton box (totalling 44L of storage) is technically the most optimal piece of luggage, but it's not exactly the most convenient thing to haul around.

Comment: A soft sided bag to the given sizes with soft grips and shoulder strap. And there are many of those for sale.

Comment: @Willeke soft sided bags are often problematic because they allow one to put in too much stuff. A hard-shell bag has no such issues.

Comment: How is this not Too Broad considering there are many hundreds of luggage manufacturers world-wide?

Comment: @CGCampbell very very few models are *exactly* within Ryanair's luggage limits and even fewer are optimized to waste as little space as possible.

Comment: @JonathanReez how do you know? have you looked at every maker? The point of Too Broad isn't just that there may be too many answers, because as you say, there _may_ only be one or two, but that there are too many choices to begin with. The OP asks for _the biggest_, not _name a single example of_ or some such.

Comment: @CGCampbell Searching every single suitcase available for sale in Czech Republic, I came down to ~10 models out of 1000, which is not much.

Comment: @JonathanReez, You did not narrow down the question to Czech Republic, nor to hard sided luggage, although you did reject the comment which advised using soft sided bags. Not sure about Czech Republic, here in the Netherlands there are many shops selling cases which are not specialized in luggage, which will widen the search a lot more.

Comment: @Willeke edited my post to make it more specific. Is it good now?

Comment: @JonathanReez No, still way to broad in my opinion.

Comment: This is the largest hard shell suitcase that I found (within Ryanair dimensions): https://www.amazon.co.uk/HAUPTSTADTKOFFER-Hard-side-Luggage-Orange-Glossy/dp/B007AU6T76 - 42 liters of volume. Most people would use softshell, though, as it is typically lighter, and Ryanair has quite low weight restrictions.

Comment: Don't forget that the dimensions must include wheels and handles.

Comment: According to the description, the one that I linked above does so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this a trick question? The first two companies jumping to mind with hardshells and Europe are Samsonite and Rimowa. The [Samsonite Cosmolite 55](http://www.samsonite.co.uk/cosmolite-3.0-spinner-55cm/73349.html?dwvar_73349_color=1673&cgid=SAMS312#start=2&cgid=SAMS312) and the [Rimowa Tapas 55](http://www.selfridges.com/CA/en/cat/rimowa-topas-four-wheel-titanium-cabin-suitcase-55cm_413-84001417-94452/) are both 55cm x 40cm x 20cm. Both are readily available worldwide.

Comment: Litres of capacity of luggage is not particularly well defined, however odd this sounds. There's a lot of shenanigans going on, some companies are more truthful than others. Noone is loading tens of thousands of one cubic centrimetre cubes in a luggage to produce the One And True Volume. Which with softshells wouldn't be possible anyways.

Comment: Wheels, handles and even the layer of material to make the shell all eat into the capacity, and that is not even considering rounded corners and less than square cross sections in the middle of the case.